# Should I tell my new boss that I apply for a job she will be interviewing?

Tags: new-job

I applied for a position that was 30 hours and got offered a position for 18 hours (they split the post between me and another and added a few hours). The salary was 3500 less than originally stated (already handed my notice in).
My question is, I have applied for another position. Much the same as the one i have accepted but full time hours.

Should I speak to my new boss to let her know I applied as she will be interviewing ?

I don't want to come across as not wanting the original position (especially if I don't get an interview or the new job applied for)- I just need more hours and I would gain a qualification along side it.

Comment: Your question is rather confusing. Is "the other role" with the same company?

Comment: Yes, tell her. Don't make it a surprise. If she doesn't want to interview you, that's fine. But do tell her. You don't have a choice. Telling her will avoid any unnecessary drama if she doesn't pay attention to who is on the roaster to interview.

Comment: Where did you give notice? At this same employer?

Answer (score 5):

Since it is the same group and your same boss will interview you, I say definitely tell her. She will know anyway. I think it's a pretty normal thing for you to do, and you can emphasize you are going for a full time role.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's within the company and she's the one doing the Interviewing - yes. Absolutely you should tell her.

You can raise that the hours and pay was less than you expected, which is why you are re-applying internally. Although if she is responsible for interviewing, she should know this.

Answer (score 0):

I often find that people respond well to honesty.
Your situation is easy to understand and should be easy to deal with for your boss.

Try to put yourself in her shoes.  What does she get out of you working more hours compared to someone else?
I know that I would rather hire someone that I know than take the risk (and yes, it is a bigger risk) to hire someone outside your (net)work.